How fork() copies pcb
Currently working on adding a feature for linux kernel, I'm trying to add a field for each process.
My idea is to add that new field to the pcb struct and initialize it to 0 for init process.
The question is, should I change the implementation of fork syscall? I tried to read the source code and I find it ambiguous, sometimes it copies the pcb for the new process with memcpy and sometimes it's assigning field by field from the father process pcb. What is the correct approach for this? Will the original fork syscall copy the new pcb field?

Isn't there a Linux developers discussion group where you could raise this question?

I'm new to this and this is also a feature for learning purposes only

If by "I'm new to this" you mean that you're new to programming or to C, then I think you should cut your teeth on something much simpler before you turn to hacking the Linux kernel.  Probably on several simpler things.  There are multiple reasons why the kernel is not a good context for learning about C programming generally.

I mean new to linux kernel programming

Well then, I feel confident that you would find people on the Linux developers list who would be interested in helping others learn about kernel development.  SO is not a particularly fruitful place to ask about implementation details of specific pieces of software.  You might get a useful answer here, but the chances would be much better in a place that is focused on kernel development.

What is a pcb struct?

@IanAbbott Process Control Block, I think. It's the structure that represents a process.

Nothing really uses the fork syscall any more. It's only there for backwards compatibility.

@Barmar So that would be struct task_struct although it really represents a thread.

@IanAbbott Possibly. I'm not an expert on the Linux kernel. PCB is a generic term in OS design, individual operating systems may use their own wording.

"I tried to read the source code and I find it ambiguous, ..." - Instead of providing only your summations, your post could be improved by citing the code you are referring to.
